# Is It possible to serve a folder directly from Azure Storage using Blazor server app with C# code

Tags: c#

Is there any chance to serve a folder directly from Azure Storage as a single entity using a Blazor server app with C# code, without downloading the folder, listing all files locally and zip.

I tried serving a folder as single entity from local storage. I want to serve a folder as a single entity directly from Azure Storage container without downloading the whole folder, listing all files locally and zip - is it possible?

Because all files which I am planning to serve those are static files like (HTML files), using C# code.